# Generate csv file in python - using zip of lists with a multidimensional list

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have run into a particular problem that I can't seem to find the answer to while working on an application.

I am attempting to create a csv file that would have nearly 75 columns. I don't want to manually create 75 lists though (it just seems excessive). I already have a list of column names for the first row in the csv file. Since I am having a hard time articulating my own question I am going to attempt to show you what I want to accomplish in code:

```
list1 = ['a','b']
list2 = ['c','d']
list3 = [['e,'f'],['g','h']]
```

Generally what I do at this point is I create a zip of lists and set up to write to a csv file:

```
csvrows = zip(list1,list2,list3)
filename = 'mytest.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
     linkwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
     for row in csvrows:
          linkwriter.writerow(row)
```

The problem here is that I believe this would create a csv file that would look something like:

```
a,c,ef
b,d,gh
```

But the type of csv file I want would be of the format:

```
a,c,e,f
b,d,g,h
```

Comment: Without knowing all the `lists`, it's not really possible to provide a full solution.  However, for your example `list1.extend(list3[0])` and `list2.extend(list3[1])`.  Otherwise start typing and use the solution below.

Comment: Would that actually solve it though? Correct me if I am wrong (not super familiar with extend) but it seems like that would just create a 3rd row - for the example I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could `zip()` together 75 columns.

But no, don't do that. You'll be happier using `[dictwriter][1]`
with 75 distinct keys in each row.

Comment: The `lists` already exist (apparently), in some form, and he didn't want to retype them.  I agree with you though.

Comment: I suppose I can go with this, and I agree that dictwriter may be the way to go over the zip. 
Still curious if there is a more elegant way though. At this point I have spent more time creating this question than it would take to create the lists of the keys, but I am pretty curious.